# Using Valet with php version installed via MacPorts

Tags: macports, laravel-valet

I have an old MacBook Pro running Catalina OS so Homebrew doesn't support my upgrade from php 8.0 to php 8.1. I managed to install php 8.1 using MacPorts instead of Homebrew:

```
php -v 

PHP 8.1.24 (cli) (built: Oct  2 2023 08:40:04) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.24, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.24, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Is there anyway I can use Valet with this php version? When I try to use it Valet says it's not installed and tries to install it again via Homebrew:

```
valet use php81 

Installing php@8.1...
[php@8.1] is not installed, installing it now via Brew...
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Valet doesn't support Macports, only Homebrew

https://github.com/laravel/valet/issues/926